# redis updating a key with the same value and ttl

Tags: redis, ttl

Does redis update the key value and ttl if I set the **same** key value and ttl again before the current ttl expires? When I do so, it doesn't seem to do anything, and the keys expire after the previous set timeout. 
The code is pretty simple - write the same keys in redis over and over again with the same value and same ttl - but looks like I should be getting the key and setting the new ttl value instead. Is this the case?

Comment: Please share the code to reproduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will update the value and the TTL.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does redis update the key value and ttl if I set the same key value and ttl again before the current ttl expires?
->**yes, it definitely update**  new ttl and value for the key